# How to get the nearest number number out of two number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have one column in dataframe with (int) values, and want to change the value to the nearest number out of two other column values.

```
df =
| value | first_num | second_num
| 131   | 134       | 129
| 157   | 154       | 159
|111.5  | 114       | 109
| 66.5  | 64        | 69

expected = 
| value | first_num | second_num
| 129   | 134       | 129
| 159   | 154       | 159
| 114   | 114       | 109
| 69    | 64        | 69
```

It should select the number which is closest to the value. If the value is equidistance from both the number, then it should select the bigger number.

And most important, I don't want to use iterrows. I am searching for solution with np.where or anything else, but not iterrows.

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I have tried this
 ```df['value'] = np.where(abs(value-first_num) < abs(value-second_num), df['first_num'], df['second_num]')``` but, doesn't have solution where ```abs(value-first_num) == abs(value-second_num)```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for multiple conditions:

```
A = abs(df['value']-df['first_num'])
B = abs(df['value']-df['second_num'])
df['value'] = np.select([A < B, A > B],
                        [df['first_num'], df['second_num']],
                        df[['first_num', 'second_num']].max(1))
```

output:

```
   value  first_num  second_num
0    129        134         129
1    159        154         159
2    114        114         109
3     69         64          69
```

Comment: It fails for the input
value= 116.115,  first_num=116.09, second_num=116.14
expected - value = 116.14 ;;
result-value = 116.09

Comment: @Jay if you're using floating point values you have to take into account precision. Here: 0.02499... vs 0.025. You need to round the values to the desired precision ;)